# gradle sync failed due to ASCII open file

Tags: firebase, android-studio

When i try to connect my project in firebase an error raise. It shows, gradle sync failed and ASCII open file. How to solve it? Please give a way.

[image: Error Image]

Answer (score 0):

I changed dependency at `gradle.build` - Project as follows :

```
dependencies { classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0' classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0' }
```